# USB pen drive not detected

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers

I have an HP Pro 3130MT running Windows 7. My USB pen drives work fine on any other computer except this one. Sometimes is says something like "..device driver installation failed" and sometimes it does not detect it at all (at any port).

The thing is, I am using a TP-Link wireless adapter that works fine on every port.

EDIT:

I tried removing ALL USB drivers from device manager, and while the USB was on, I restarted the PC. On boot, everything was installed back ok, and USB worked! But, on removal, I am back to the same scenario

Comment: Yes. Updated drivers yesterday

Comment: It is. i tried removing ALL USB drivers from device manager, and while the USB was on, i restarted the PC. On boot, everything was installed back ok, and USB worked! But, on removal, I am back to the same scenario

Comment: What I would check for is the USB Power Settings and disable "USB selective suspend setting". Then I would run chkdsk on that pen drive from the pc that recognizes it. then I would uninstall all the USB pen drivers and reboot the affected machine and then plug the pen drive in question.

Answer (score 0):

Which Win 7 are you running?
It was pre-installed with the machine by HP?

It should have no issues whatsoever accessing USB devices via any port. You don't need extra drivers and all drives should be fine on it.
As your drives do not fail to access on any other computer, we can conclude they are operational; so not one of the 'ducks' which are culpable here.

That eliminates all but Win7 installation or the hardware.
Since USB wireless adapter works on every port then hardware isn't at fault, *unless* the TP-link uses signficantly less voltage than a pen drive (almost certainly not), not being an electrical engineer it is only an estimate of what I understand as the wireless adapter would have a transmitting circuit.

Unless there is something which has been *added* to your Win7 installation to impede the code which should allow access to volumes via USB ports - overly eager AntiVirus execution interception, *or* your installation has been compromised by malware...

Ok, what happens when you connect a HD via USB ports? Does it make any difference if you connect a powered HD - that is an external HD that has it's own powersouce?

From the argument it would seem to suggest your Win7 installation needs redoing.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest doing a Safe Mode install of the drivers if you can.

Boot normally
Remove the drivers completely from the system
Reboot to Safe Mode
Install the Driver
Reboot normally
insert device into USB port

Hopefully this will clean things up so that the device will work after being removed and r-attached to the computer.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me once. Try backing up your USB contents on another PC and then reformatting your USB. This is how I solved my issue with me. Your new USB should be now detected on your PC.